# Import error with Tkinter and python3.5

Tags: tkinter, ubuntu-12.04, python-3.5

I am having trouble running matplotlib.pyplot and tkinter with python3.5. I am on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.  I see that python3-tk installed when I type dpkg -l python3-tk. How else should I troubleshoot?

Is python3-tk only for python3.2 not python3.5?

Examples below with python3.2 versus python3.5

```
machine:~$ /usr/bin/python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Jun 18 2015, 21:46:58)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>> exit()

machine:~$ /usr/bin/python3.5
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 17 2016, 17:38:18)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-tk package')
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package
```

python3-tk is installed

```
machine:~$ dpkg -l python3-tk
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                         Version                      Description
    +++-============================-============================-

========================================================================
ii  python3-tk                   3.2.3-1                      Tkinter - Writing Tk applications with Python 3.x
```

Comment: I suspect that _tkinter.so, compiled from _tkinter.c, is somewhere in /usr/bin/python3 and that it also needs to be in the corresponding place in /usr/bin/python3.5.  Whether is needs to be recompiled for 3.5 (as would be the case on Windows) or merely copied, I do not know.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

This command will install tkinter for your default python3 only, so python3.5 ImportError.

You can run the following command to install for python3.5

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-tk
```

Comment: In my case, I got error **E: Package 'python3.5-tk' has no installation candidate.** At last, I fixed by upgrading my python 3.5 to 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

Change the matplotlib backend to 'agg' or some other noninteractive option. Something like the following:

matplotlib.use('agg')

[More info here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8929) (in the context of Docker, where I faced this issue and successfully solved it):

Answer (score 0):

The python3-tk libraries were installed under the 3.2 version, not 3.5.  Python3-tk was uninstalled and python3.5-tk was installed instead

Answer (score 0):

I tried using this command in ubuntu16.02 it works

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-tk
```

as by default i had python2.7 installed.you can refer this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886617/how-can-i-install-tkinter-for-both-python-3-4-and-python-3-5)